# Using string.replace()

Tags: java

I am using string.replace() in some coding, and I do not know if I am using it correctly.

For example:

```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter char to replace *:");
   Sring wildcard = scan.scannextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter name with wildcard.");
   String filename = scan.scannextLine();

   System.out.println(filename.replace(String "*", String wildcard));
```

Will give me an error saying that ')' or ';' is expected in various places.

Comment: Please review java syntax. What do you think `.replace(String "*" ...` does?

Comment: `filename.replace("*", wildcard)`.

Comment: Moreover `s/Sring/String/`.

Comment: Also, `java.util.Scanner` doesn't have a `scannextLine()` method.

Comment: Lucky I'm not a compiler..

Comment: @MarounMaroun Being a java compiler, you couldn't even `SIGSEGV`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not specify the class String before your string literal.

```
filename.replace("*", wildcard)
```

And `nextLine()` is an existing method in the Scanner class. `scannextLine()` isn't.

```
String wildcard = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: That's one of ∞ problems.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I like the ∞!

Comment: @devnull next time I'll animate it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun And maybe have a freehand circle around it too!

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the type when calling filename.repalce; this isn't needed. eg

```
System.out.println(filename.replace("*", wildcard));
```

String is also misspelled when declaring wildcard

Comment: See my comment to @MartijnCourteaux. (Note that beautiful ∞ there)